# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to BitVectorFlowMap<A>

Tags: java, debugging

I am getting a cmpilation error on return super.clone() line. Error says Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to BitVectorFlowMap

```
public BitVectorFlowMap<A> clone() {
    try
    {
    return super.clone();
    }
    catch(Exception e){ return null; }
}
```

I am not able to understand what is the error saying.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `super.clone()` is `Object`, as that is the direct ancestor of `BitVectorFlowMap`, and therefore it is not a valid return value for `clone()`, which must return something of type `BitVectorFlowMap`. You'll have to actually construct a new instance of `BitVectorFlowMap` with the same data.

Comment: Will casing it into BitVectorFlowMap work?
return (BitVectorFlowMap<A>) super.clone();

Comment: Yes, that should work -- you might need to change more attributes of what you get back from `super.clone()` if `BitVectorFlowMap` refers to data that `Object` does not...